# Python 2.7.13 UnicodeEncodeError and Special Characters

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, ascii, encode

I am writing a simple python program that retrieves information from a website, the problem is that there are some words which contain special characters such as
"°", "Ψ" and many more.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
r = urllib.urlopen('http://www.samplepage.sample').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
text = soup.find_all("a", class_="some_class")
for word in text:
    word = word.get_text()
    word = word.encode('utf-8')
    print word
```

the output should be "°", but instead of that, I get "Â°"

If i try to encode it with ascii i get the classical UnicodeEncodeError:

```
for word in text:
    word = word.get_text()
    word = word.encode('ascii')
    print word

>>> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 7-8: 
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the _samplepage.sample_ here ?

Comment: It's just any web page

Comment: We can't see the output of your script until you provide the _url_

Comment: the output should be "°", but instead of that, I get "Â°"

Comment: How do I know the output should be `°` or `Â°` ?

Comment: Because I know how the output should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably happens because you decode the string using the wrong codec.

Try printing the string, and before encoding it with **utf-8** first **you need to decode** the string using the right codec. Then you'll get a Unicode object, which you can print and should be displayed right.

If it's a special char outside of the ascii mapping, you'll need the Unicode object to display it properly.

Try do the following:

```
new_word = word.decode('latin-1')
print new_code
word = word.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: @devmon I've added a snippet to the answer for you to try